# Why I cannot change a value of angular property in html?

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-bootstrap, ng-animate

I have a tooltip which popups on focus using angular popovers. What I need to do is when I click a button, to change it to popup on blur. It changes but doesn't change the tooltip behavior.

Here is the plunkr: http://plnkr.co/edit/L1oeZQrQdF0AdJMKVsG6?p=preview

Below is the code:

```
<input type="text" 
          ng-model="value" 
          value="{{value}}" 
          uib-popover-template="htmlPopover"
          popover-trigger="{{triggerOn}}" 
          popover-popup-close-delay="1000" 
          class="form-control">


     <script type="text/ng-template" id="myPopoverTemplate.html">
        <div>
          <button ng-click="test()"><b style="color: red">Add message</b></button>
        </div>
    </script>
```

controller

```
function ($scope) {
    $scope.value = "Click me!";
    $scope.dynamicPopover = {
        content: 'Hello, World!',
        templateUrl: 'myPopoverTemplate.html',
        title: 'Title'
    };

    $scope.message = 'Trigger: none';

    $scope.triggerOn = "focus";

    $scope.changeTrigger = function(){

       $scope.triggerOn = "blur";

       $scope.message = "Should trigger on blur";
    }

    $scope.test = function(){
        $scope.value = "test me click";
    }

    $scope.htmlPopover = 'myPopoverTemplate.html';
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Looking at [the source code](https://github.com/angular-ui/bootstrap/blob/master/src/tooltip/tooltip.js#L150) for the `uib-popover` directive, one can that **the triggers are set when the directive is linked**.

```
    compile: function(tElem, tAttrs) {
      var tooltipLinker = $compile(template);

      return function link(scope, element, attrs, tooltipCtrl) {
        var tooltip;
        var tooltipLinkedScope;
        var transitionTimeout;
        var showTimeout;
        var hideTimeout;
        var positionTimeout;
        var appendToBody = angular.isDefined(options.appendToBody) ? options.appendToBody : false;
        //TRIGGERS SET AT LINK TIME
        var triggers = getTriggers(undefined);
        var hasEnableExp = angular.isDefined(attrs[prefix + 'Enable']);
        var ttScope = scope.$new(true);
        var repositionScheduled = false;
        var isOpenParse = angular.isDefined(attrs[prefix + 'IsOpen']) ? $parse(attrs[prefix + 'IsOpen']) : false;
        var contentParse = options.useContentExp ? $parse(attrs[ttType]) : false;
        var observers = [];
        var lastPlacement;
```

If one wants to change how the directive triggers, the directive needs to be re-compiled with the `$compile` service on each change to the triggers.